Complexity of a variation of edge cover for paths
Consider the following problem.
Given a directed acyclic graph $G=(V,E)$ with a designated source vertex $s\in V$ and sink vertex $t\in V$, and natural number $k$.
Find a smallest set $E'\subseteq E$ of edges, such that every path from $s$ to $t$ contains at least $k$ edges from $E'$ (if such a set $E'$ exists)?
Or, as a decision problem, is there such a set $E'$ of size smaller than $m$?
For $k=1$ this seems to be solvable as a min-cut/max-flow problem and hence seems polynomial. But what about $k>1$? Is it still polynomial, or NP Complete?
It seems to be a kind of variation on edge cover, covering paths instead of vertices and generalized to covering $k$ times, but I cannot find related problems, perhaps I am missing the right keywords.
I am also interested in the following generalization of the problem with edge weights. In particular, should the above problem be polynomially solvable, then is the following also (pseudo-)polynomial?
Given a double edge-weighted directed acyclic graph $G=(V,E,w_1,w_2)$ with a designated source vertex $s\in V$ and sink vertex $t\in V$ and a natural number $W$. Both edge weights map to non-negative integers. (We may assume that for all $e\in E$, $w_2(e)\leq w_1(e)$.)
What is a smallest set $E'\subseteq E$ of edges, such that for each path from $s$ to $t$, the sum of $w_2$-weights for the edges from $E'$ and $w_1$-weights for the other edges amounts to a total weight of at most $W$ (if such a set $E'$ exists).
I.e., for every path $\pi\subseteq E$ from $s$ to $t$:
$$
\sum_{e\in \pi\cap E'} w_2(e) + \sum_{e\in \pi\cap (E\backslash E')} w_1(e) \leq W
$$
Any insights, keywords, or directions to algorithmic solutions are appreciated.

What you are asking for has been studied in the general graph setting under the term "length bounded flows and cuts". See the following paper which shows NP-Completeness and hardness of approximation.
@article{baier2010length,
title={Length-bounded cuts and flows},
author={Baier, Georg and Erlebach, Thomas and Hall, Alexander and K{"o}hler, Ekkehard and Kolman, Petr and Pangr{'a}c, Ond{\v{r}}ej and Schilling, Heiko and Skutella, Martin},
journal={ACM Transactions on Algorithms (TALG)},
volume={7},
number={1},
pages={1--27},
year={2010},
publisher={ACM New York, NY, USA}
}

It looks like I may have misunderstood the OPs question.  I assumed that one wants to remove the fewest edges from G such that in the residual graph the shortest s-t path has length at least k. The OP's question seems different on a second look.
